# objective c - Break statement

Tags: objective-c

deleted
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Game.h"

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        Game *myGame = [[Game alloc]init];
        
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your problem is?

Comment: @Andrea:His title is his problem...

Comment: sorry im very new at this, ive solved it already though, i just had to re arrange my brackets because they closed out the break statement from the while loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`break` must be in `loop` or `switch`.

Your `break` is outside the loop, only in the `if` section. That is why you are getting the error.

Comment: yes thank you, i realized the the brackets were out of place. sorry.